# Pinescript - different results on backtesting vs live alert

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, back-testing

I have created a basic script with the following buy and sell conditions and  calc_on_order_fills = true.

```
strategy("Current strategy code", overlay=true,use_bar_magnifier = true, pyramiding = 0, calc_on_order_fills = true)

length = input.int(14, minval=1)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
sma= ta.sma(close, 200)

buycondition = ta.crossover(k,d)
sellcondition = ta.crossunder(k,d)

if (buycondition) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    
if (sellcondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short")
```

When I compare the results on tradingview backtest vs the alert I've set up they're different.

Would this be because the backtest is recalculating once the order is filled? Or only has the data for the open, high and low of the candle?
Is there something I can add so that the alert does exactly the same trades as the backtest?

I tried changing the code to only enter trades based off the close of the candle but this had a bad effect on the results, so would ideally like to replicate the backtest process for my alerts.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to provide your full (or at least more complete) code please? - including the alerts you mentioned, formatting, pine header etc. This would allow for a more complete answer.

Currently it just looks like you need to indent your if statement expressions...

Comment: Hi @theCrypster, I've edited the code in my original question to show the full script. 

I've noticed where the issue lies - When watching live, the strategy will only open one position per candle. However, when I refresh the page and run the strategy again it often thinks it has opened two positions in the same candle. Sometimes it also does this on the live alerts but I can't figure out how it decides if it should open two positions on one candle or not? Sometimes the live alerts and backtest match